# Cleaning a messy Dataset

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, data-analysis

I got an originally txt file converted to csv.
I have the column names but there is practically one row in the
unprocessed dataset.
How do I clean the dataset using pandas,numpy exc.methods so that each string/int between every comma will be placed in seperated column with the proper column name?
Thanks,
Ido

```
cols = ['AIRLINE_ID','AIRLINE_NAME','ALIAS','IATA','ICAO','CALLSIGN','COUNTRY','ACTIVE'
]
```

[Airlines_raw_dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Yi1V.jpg)

I looked for videos regarding this topic on youtube but I didn't encounter specific info for this highly dirty dataset.

Comment: How did you read the CSV into your Python code?

Comment: using the pandas read_csv method

Answer (score 0):

Pandas Has a built in method for reading csv files. It may be used in this fashion

```
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
```

You can read more about this method here -> [Official Docs](https://Pandas%20Has%20a%20built%20in%20method%20for%20reading%20csv%20files.%20It%20may%20be%20used%20in%20this%20fashion%20%20%20%20%20%20%20df%20=%20pd.read_csv(%27filename.csv%27)%20%20You%20can%20read%20more%20about%20this%20method%20here%20-%3E%20%5BOfficial%20Docs%5D%5B1%5D%20%20%20%20%20%5B1%5D:%20https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)